# How to copy a particular line of text from HTML page via PHP?

Tags: php, html

I want to grab html code from a web page and I want to take some specific number of lines from that html code. I am able to fetch all information from webpage but cannot do copy. How can I do so?

My code is-

```
        $sourceURL = file($link);


        $title = '';

        foreach ($sourceURL as $value) {

            if(strpos($value, '<h1 class="title') !== false){

                //if it return true, wanna copy that line and store into $title variable.

            } else {
                echo "nothing";
            }
}
```

Any clue, how to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use external library e.g:
http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

```
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file($link);

$title = $html->find('h1[class=title]');
```

Comment: Thank you..  I found the solution already. 
By the way, I can't use external all libraries becoz this code is going to use Laravel.

Comment: If you use Laravel then you can just use Bundle for HTML Dom e.g http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html

Comment: thats really nice package. Let's give a try. TQVM

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. I found the solution.

The best way to copy it, just use the value-

```
if(strpos($value, '<h1 class="title') !== false){

            $title = $value;

        }
```